# Select certain row based on my condition

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
| id | product_id | price   |  group  |
| 1  | 123123     |   100   |   1     |
| 2  | 123123     |   200   |  d845f  |
| 3  | 91123      |   150   |   1     |
| 4  | 2131238    |   100   |   1     |
| 4  | 5678689    |   250   |   1     |
```

So I want to select all prices where group is `IN (1, 'd845f')`. For some of them there is only one row output, like

```
| 3  | 91123      |   150   |   1     |
```

But for some there are two rows:

```
| 1  | 123123     |   100   |   1     |
| 2  | 123123     |   200   |  d845f  |
```

I perform selecting with something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `group` IN (1, 'd845f')
```

where `1` and `d845f` are set parameters I specify in PHP.
So there is always one row with `group = 1`, but there can optionally be second row like in example above with group `'d845f'` from my IN option.
So when I have two rows I would like MySQL to only show one of them: the one with `'d845f'`.
So how do I do it?
I would like to get all the products with `group = 1` parameter, but when `group = 'd845f'` I would like to get only one row: with `group = 'd845f'`.
I also would like to do it without nested SELECTs (JOINS are allowed).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is called `Relational Division`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  product_ID
            FROM    tableName
            WHERE   `GROUP` IN ('1','d845f')
            GROUP   BY product_ID
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT `GROUP`) = 2
        ) b ON a.product_ID = b.product_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0466/1)
- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦════════════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ PRODUCT_ID ║ PRICE ║ GROUP ║
╠════╬════════════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║     123123 ║   100 ║ 1     ║
║  2 ║     123123 ║   200 ║ d845f ║
╚════╩════════════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you'll need to check if the product_id has a group with d845f in it, and if so, use that instead of the one with 1.

This should work:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM TableName T
  JOIN (
    SELECT Product_Id, 
      MAX(IF(`GROUP`='d845f','d845f','1')) whichGroup
    FROM TableName T
    WHERE   `GROUP` IN ('1','d845f')
    GROUP BY Product_ID
    ) T2 ON 
      T.Product_Id = T2.Product_Id AND T.`GROUP` = T2.whichGroup
```

Using the `MAX` with the `IF` checks to see if a record exists for that particular product.  Then join those results on the original table.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0466/7) (Borrowed from previous poster)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a CASE statement with a LIMIT

```
SELECT group, product_id, price, id
FROM table 
WHERE group IN (1, 'd845f')
ORDER BY CASE WHEN group = 'd845f' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It works but only returns result for one product id, and I need also other rows for other product id's.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple one

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.product_id,
  a.price,
  a.`group`
FROM
  tablename a
  LEFT JOIN tablename b ON ( a.product_id = b.product_id
                       AND a.`group` <> b.`group` )
WHERE
  b.`group` IS NULL 
  OR length(a.`group`) > length(b.`group`)
```

**Note:** I have not added the condition of of group being `d845f` as I suspect that there could be 2 records of the same `product_id` having different groups. The query gets the row values of group which is greatest

Comment: I tested it, when groups are `'32z3s'` and `5` it will still return 5. If groups are `'32z3s'` and `2` it will return `'32z3s'`, so this algorithm is unstable.

Comment: @Konnigun you can change the comparison condition, I have adjusted it to chk the length of the 2 groups, the string length of the group having the maximum characters shall now be shown